# Symfony Doctrine import "join" table from database

Tags: symfony, import, doctrine

I would like to import existing tables from database into Symfony project (realise them as entities).
I used commands:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force BundleName yml
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities BundleName
```

The commands worked fine and the problem is that any "join" table (foreign keys in place) will be missing,
e.g. If I have table Order, Item and OrderItem, where OrderItem contains the mapping of Order and Item, then Symfony/Doctrine resolves Order and Item into a **many to many** relation and creates entities for Order and Item only.

Question is how can I make doctrine to import the "join" table as well and resolve it into two many to one relations with respect to the target tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine won't be able to guess the relations exactly.  It have even seen imports fail because some tables did not contain primary keys.  One to many / many to many relations are defined by the way it is used and enforced by constraints.

The import is a run-once facility.  You will have to check and update the mapping yourself afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the input. After I put a single valued PK (used to be composite of FKs) in my "join" table, doctrine interprets it as an entity instead of just a linker. That's all I needed:)